# How do I run a command and get its exit code in fewer characters?

Tags: shell-script

I used to write my scripts like this:

```
some_command
while [ $? -ne 0 ] ; do
    sleep 1
    some_command
done
```

It always irked me that I have to write `some_command` twice. Can I put it inside the loop test section somehow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `some_command` as your test condition.

```
while ! some_command; do sleep 1; done
```

The condition will remain true as long as `some_command` exits with an error.

Or a more verbose way if you want to do additional checks:

```
while ! some_command
do 
    # add more if desired
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This looks better than mine, even though it is a one-liner ;-)

Comment: The OP might want to split it into several lines should he need to execute several commands upon failure, though :)

Comment: No reason why you can't line-break it at the semi-colons to make it multi-line.

Comment: ... or write `while ! some_command; do several; commands; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 12):

This is what the `until` loop is for:

```
until some_command
do    sleep 1
done
```

It is the logical negation of a `while` loop.

The [spec says:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

#### The `until` Loop

- The `until` loop shall continuously execute one *compound-list* as long as another *compound-list* has a non-zero exit status.
- The format of the until loop is as follows:

```
    until compound-list-1
    do    compound-list-2
    done
```

- The *compound-list-1* shall be executed, and if it has a zero exit status, the `until` command completes. Otherwise, the *compound-list-2* shall be executed, and the process repeats.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
false
while [ $? -ne 0 ] ; do
   sleep 1
   some_command
done
```

this has the disadvantage though that it always sleeps one second first

If you want to be able to exit on any of a number of commands to exit with 0 you can do :

```
while true; do
  if [ some_command ] ; then break ; fi
  if [ some_other_command ] ; then break ; fi
  sleep 1
done
```

which of course also works for just `some_command`

Comment: The second example shouldn't include `[` and `]` around the commands.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `while ! ...` nor `until ...` works on the systems that froze their shell environment prior to POSIX.1-2001.  This, however, does.

```
while :; do
    if some command; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

If you don't need total portability, why are you writing a shell script?  Perl is *more* likely to be available than Bash.

```
sleep 1 while 0 != system qw(some command);
```

(As above, the `sleep` is only executed if the command fails.)